# Which twitter API should be used to fetch users basic information using access token instead of user_id or screen_name?

Tags: java, rest, twitter, backend

I want to implement sns login with tweeter. After user allowing my app and providing his access token, i want to fetch his basic info like user_id, name, date of birth. But from this list [Twitter API list](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index) i can not find any suitable API. Because any API that users info requires his user_id. So i need the API that simply takes his access token and returns those basic information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to call the [`verify_credentials` endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials) in order to do this. It does not require the user ID or screen name, it takes the access token as part of the auth header and then returns the signed-in user details. Note that this does not include date of birth, as that is not provided by the Twitter API.

There's also another way to do this - the first numeric part of the access token is in fact the user ID, so you could pass that to the `users/lookup` endpoint!